# Selenium does not find element by it's xPath

Tags: java, selenium, facebook, selenium-webdriver

Trying to upload some image from Facebook by its xPath, without lucky, any other way to do it?

[image]

Java:

```
var xPathContato = "//*[@id=\"mount_0_0_lv\"]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]";
WebElement wb = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(xPathContato));

String image = wb.getAttribute("src");
 
URL imageURL = new URL(image );
BufferedImage saveImage = ImageIO.read(imageURL);
 
ImageIO.write(saveImage, "png", new File("facebook-img"));
```

*Error:*

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="mount_0_0_lv"]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]"}
```

Comment: You get that error because the element doesn't exists. Just because it existed when you open the developer toolbar in chrome doesn't mean it exists when you load the page in Selenium.

Comment: @WizKid Seeing you after long time. Btw, since when did Facebook allowed scraping as legal?

Comment: @DebanjanB If is not illegal, is legal.

Comment: @JamesB Haven't seen the finer ToS since FB turned Meta(verse), waiting to hear from the horse mouth ;)

Comment: I never said it was legal or illegal. I said it is against Facebook Terms of Service and therefor you risk getting banned.

Comment: @WizKid I was replying to the boy's accusations.

Comment: I was replying to @DebanjanB

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing something up. The elemnt doesn't really exit in the page you are uploading into selenium, otherwise it would be shown without any problems, but the element exist basically only in your developer toolbar of your browser.